# Can a base class be declared in C++ such that classes derived from it can only be created via a creation function?

Tags: c++, inheritance

in something like the following

```
class Base
{
protected:
    Base()
    {}

public:
    virtual void initialize()
    {}

    template<typename D, typename... Ts>
    static std::shared_ptr<D> create(Ts... args)
    {
        auto d = std::shared_ptr<D>(new D(args...)); 
        d->initialize();
        return d;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    private:
        int value_;

    protected:

    public:

        Derived(int v) : value_(v)
        {}

        void initialize() override
        {
            //Do something with value_
        }
};


int main()
{
    auto derived = Base::create<Derived>(42);
    // etc.

    return 0;
}
```

The above works as expected but if Base was part of a class library that the user of the library was extending by implementing Derived, there is nothing preventing the user of the library from creating a Derived via its public constructor and thus initialize won't be called.

In such a library/library user scenario how could one enforce usage of something like Base::create(...) for Derived class creation?

For example, if Base::Base() is made private rather than protected the code won't compile because Derived::Derived() wont be able to access it.

Comment: Why can't the Base constructor be made _protected_?

Comment: it can be. But a class that is derived from it can then use it and not use Base::create. The Derived class's constructor can be made protected too which would enforce usage of Base::create but that would have to be done by the class library user -- author of Derived -- and nothing is forcing the user to do this.

Comment: I assume you've burned some brain cells trying to simplify by eliminating initialize and building its functionality into the appropriate constructor?

Comment: What you are trying to do is essentially a "2-phase-construction" and a handy "factory function" to wrap the 2PC.. Both are pretty basic concepts. IMHO, [educate u̶s̶e̶r̶s̶ developers instead of protecting them](https://github.com/davybrion/companysite-dotnet/blob/master/content/blog/2009-04-educate-developers-instead-of-protecting-them.md) because after this case, you will soon find another and another scenarios, probably incrementally harder to prevent. IMHO, it's their responsibility to RTFM and use the lib properly. Neither 2PC nor FF is that hard to be worth wasting so much time on that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a bit finicky, but I think it covers all bases:

```
class Base
{
protected:

    // Token is only visible to Derived, and only constructible by Base
    class token {
        friend Base;
        token() {};
    };

    // Constructing Base requires a token
    Base(token)
    {}

public:
    // bla

    template<typename D, typename... Ts>
    static std::shared_ptr<D> create(Ts... args)
    {
        auto d = std::shared_ptr<D>(new D({}, args...));
        // Token is created here          ^^ 

        // bla
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    // bla

    public:

        // Derived receives and forwards the token to Base
        // The implicit copy constructor is accessible
        Derived(token t, int v) : Base(t), value_(v)
        {}

    // bla
};
```

Thus, no one can write `Derived d(Base::token{}, 42)` because `token` is inaccessible. `Derived` itself can name `token` and pass one around, but cannot create one: only `Base`'s `create` function can.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is just to make sure that initialize function is called by derived classes make it pure virtual.

I would suggest to use Non-Virtual Interface(NVI) idiom.

In this way library users are enforced to implement doInitialize function in derived classes.

```
class Base
{
protected:
  Base()
  {

  }

public:
  void initialize()
  {
    doInitialize();
  }

  template<typename D, typename... Ts>
  static std::shared_ptr<D> create(Ts... args)
  {
    auto d = std::shared_ptr<D>(new D(args...));
    d->initialize();
    return d;
  }

  virtual ~Base() = default;

protected:
  virtual void doInitialize() = 0;   
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
  int value_;

public:  
  Derived(int v) : value_(v)
  {}

private:
  void doInitialize() override
  {
    //Do something with value_
  }
};

int main()
{
    auto derived = Base::create<Derived>(42);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This ensures users of Base must implement derived’s initialize member function but I don’t see how it ensures that initialize must be called after construction of a derived.